# Blank page on state change of Material UI Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hey I have tried a lot of things but I can't seem to get this thing to work I am trying to make a simple modal using material UI but whenever I try to change state it's showing me a blank white page. does anyone have any idea why is it happening here's my code
a

```
    import {Button,Modal} from "@material-ui/core";
import {useState} from "react";

import RegisterBody from '../Register/RegisterForm'
import LoginBody from '../Login/LoginForm'

const UserModel = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
    const [isLoginModel, setLoginModel] = useState();


    const [MainModelBody] = useState(LoginBody);

    function handleRegister() {
        if (!isLoginModel) {
            console.log("Register")
            //Todo: Send Register Request
        } else {
            MainModelBody.setState(RegisterBody)
            setLoginModel(false)
        }
    }

    function handleSignIn() {
        if (isLoginModel) {
            console.log("Login")
            //Todo: send Sign in request
        } else {
            MainModelBody.setState(LoginBody)
            setLoginModel(true)
        }
    }

    function handleUserModel() {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Button className="userActionButton" onClick={handleUserModel}>Sign In</Button>

            <Modal open={isOpen}
                   onClose={!isOpen}
                   disablePortal
                   disableEnforceFocus
                   disableAutoFocus
                   aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
                   aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"

            >
                <div className = 'UserModel'>
                    <LoginBody/>
                    <Button onClick={handleRegister}>Register</Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign In</Button>
                </div>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
}

export default UserModel
```

LoginBody

```
import {useState} from 'react';

import  LoginElements from './LoginElements';
import {FormControl} from "@material-ui/core";

const LoginForm = ()=> {
    const [email, setEmail]  = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword]  = useState('')

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const user = {email, password}
        console.log(user)
    };

    return (
      <div className="form">
          <FormControl noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <LoginElements
                  email={email}
                  password={password}
                  setEmail={setEmail}
                  setPassword={setPassword}
              />
          </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
}
export default LoginForm;
```

LoginElements

```
import {Button, TextField} from "@material-ui/core";

const LoginElements = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <TextField label="Email" type="email" required value={props.email} onChange={(e) => props.setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
            <br/>
            <TextField label="Password" type="password" required value={props.password} onChange={(e) => props.setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <br/>
            <Button variant="contained" type="submit">Login</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" type="register">Register</Button>
            <br/>
            <label>{props.email}</label>
            <label>{props.password}</label>
        </>
    )
}

export default LoginElements;
```

RegisterBody

```
    import {useState} from 'react';

import  RegisterElements from './RegisterElements';

const LoginForm = ()=> {
    const [email, setEmail]  = useState('')
    const [confirmEmail, setConfirmEmail]  = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword]  = useState('')
    const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword]  = useState('')

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const user = {email, password}
        console.log(user)
    };

    return (
        <div className="form">
            <form  noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <RegisterElements
                    email={email}
                    confirmEmail={email}
                    password={password}
                    confirmPassword={password}
                    setEmail={setEmail}
                    setConfirmEmail={setEmail}
                    setPassword={setPassword}
                    setConfirmPassword={setPassword}
                />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
export default LoginForm;
```

Register Elements

```
import {Button, TextField} from "@material-ui/core";

const RegisterElements = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <TextField label="Confirm Email" type="email" required value={props.email}
                       onChange={(e) => props.setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
            <TextField label="Confirm Email" type="email" required value={props.confirmEmail}
                       onChange={(e) => props.setConfirmEmail(e.target.value)}/>
            <br/>
            <TextField label="Password"
                       type="password"
                       required value={props.password}
                       onChange={(e) => props.setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <TextField label="Confirm Password" required value={props.confirmPassword}
                       onChange={(e) => props.setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <br/>
            <Button variant="contained" type="Login">Login</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" type="submit">Login</Button>

            <label>{props.email}</label>
            <label>{props.password}</label>
        </>
    )
}

export default RegisterElements;
```

My apologies for bad code i am new with react

Comment: What is in your LoginBody component?

Comment: What are `MainModelBody.setState(RegisterBody)` or `MainModelBody.setState(LoginBody)` doing? Please include all relevant code in your question. These seem highly suspect to me. Are you really trying to conditionally render either the `RegisterBody` or `LoginBody` component and pass additional props?

Comment: Main body.setState is just an attempt to change body with state i wasn't successful with that problem is when i set open={true} in the model it displays the model perfectly but when i do the same with statechange and userActionButton it shows me blank page for some reason i dont know

Comment: Edit your post to include the code rather than post it as a comment

Comment: as you said yes i am trying to conditionally render either one of them but yea not using them right now if you know a better way please let me know

Comment: I added my other code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "toggling" the `isLoginModel` state but you only render `LoginBody` in the JSX.

You should be able to use the `isLoginModel` state and conditionally render either the `LoginBody` or `RegisterBody` component into the modal body. There's really no need for the extra state to hold a component reference.

```
import {Button,Modal} from "@material-ui/core";
import {useState} from "react";

import RegisterBody from '../Register/RegisterForm'
import LoginBody from '../Login/LoginForm'

const UserModel = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  const [isLoginModel, setLoginModel] = useState(true); // login by default

  function handleRegister() {
    if (!isLoginModel) {
      console.log("Register");
      // TODO: Send Register Request
    } else {
      setLoginModel(false);
    }
  }

  function handleSignIn() {
    if (isLoginModel) {
      console.log("Login");
      // TODO: send Sign in request
    } else {
      setLoginModel(true);
    }
  }

  function handleUserModel() {
    setIsOpen(isOpen => !isOpen);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button className="userActionButton" onClick={handleUserModel}>Sign In</Button>

      <Modal open={isOpen}
        onClose={!isOpen}
        disablePortal
        disableEnforceFocus
        disableAutoFocus
        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
      >
        <div className='UserModel'>
          {isLoginModel ? <LoginBody /> : <RegisterBody />} // <-- condition render
          <Button onClick={handleRegister}>Register</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign In</Button>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: okay yea that answers the conditional rendering were you able to see why i am getting blank white screen when i open model using state boolean?

Comment: @Bhavishya I've pored over your code and I don't see any overt reasons why a page would be blank other than I suspect CSS. Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the blank page issue? I'll try the same.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-ride-ns1dj i hope this is visible for you?

Comment: @Bhavishya It's rendering for me, I had to apply some CSS to get it to look more like a modal. See my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blank-page-on-state-change-of-material-ui-modal-mvcq6) attempt. Since the `Modal` is just the base component for several other MUI components, you may want to use the `Dialog` component instead.